# Manually send WooCommerce order from pending payment to payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have a renewal based site. I'm using WooCommerce with WooCommerce Subscription on my site.

I attached a custom function to the filter `wcs_renewal_order_created`. The filter is applied after a renewal order is created.

The custom function gave a fatal error and the renewal process got halted

Current situation:
The renewal orders are stuck on "Pending payment". I need to get those orders out of that state. I'm looking for some way to manually send my order to the payment gateway to complete the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by

1. Deleting the corrupted renewal order,
2. Process a new renewal from the subscription page
3. They retrying pending payment from the renewal order generated in step 2.

The next day, I found that there is section Subscription documentation specifically for this situation:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/scheduled-action-errors/#section-5